# An unwavering force... What do you get?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

An unwavering force.

Without it, you would not be here.

What do you get when you take it away?

Comment: Hi clinto! Firstly, where did you get this riddle from? Is it your own? If no, please edit the source of this puzzle. Is the answer to this puzzle a word?

Comment: Hi, yes this is indeed my own

Comment: Is this a shoutout to desertphile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*An unwavering force.*
*Without it, you would not be here.*

> This clues the word GRAVITY - a fundamental force of nature, without which life could not exist.

*What do you get when you take it away?*

> If we take 'IT' away from the word GRAVITY, we get **GRAVY**!

Comment: you've got it:)

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> Gravy

An unwavering force.

> Gravity is the most unwavering (constant, strong and steady) force there is

Without it, you would not be here.

> Without gravity, or atoms would be floating in space

What do you get when you take it away?

> If you remove the letters “IT” from GRAVITY you’re left with GRAVY

Comment: Wow, just 16 seconds in this one... Good to see someone else thinking the same way as me! +1

Comment: Yes, after 2 hours, came down to 16 seconds - incredible :). well done !